# Htmlspecialchars return a mistake value

Tags: php, php-7, htmlspecialchars

I'm using PHP 7.4, when I run `echo htmlspecialchars("Jours Fériés", ENT_QUOTES);` I get an empty string.
when I run `echo htmlspecialchars("Jours", ENT_QUOTES)`; I get "Jours"
How can fix this problem ?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/HHPF5 - looks ok to me. Please provide a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: What encoding is your string in…? The problem is that `htmlspecialchars` assumes the wrong encoding.

Comment: I'm using UTF-8

Comment: hi mourad, as adyson pointed the output do looks alright. there are several possible cause to your problem. one of them is character encoding, specifically the html output which dictated on  [`charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) which can be sent via http headers or meta tags. do make sure they are not conflicting. another thing to check, if the source of the string came from database, make sure it has the correct charset too. all we can do is just guess work as we cant replicate your problem.

Comment: To confirm if it's an encoding issue, try using `bin2hex` to dump a hexadecimal representation of the binary string, and compare it against this output: https://3v4l.org/tUmRV

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing encoding to "iso-8859-1" inside php.ini

Comment: Note that ISO-8859-1 has no encoding for the Euro symbol (€) so if your text has that in, it's probably actually Windows-1252, or possibly ISO-8859-15

Comment: inside the file php.ini